# Because xxx depends on places_service >=0.1.0+1 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.17.0, version solving failed

Tags: flutter

Because xxx depends on places_service >=0.1.0+1 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.17.0, version solving failed.

i tried to used `flutter clean` and `flutter upgraded` but still got same problem

Also, tried to used `flutter doctor -v` to checked, I got this information

```
Returning 1970-01-01 11:00:00.000 instead.
[!] Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702], locale zh-TW)
    ! Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown on channel unknown at C:\flutter
      Currently on an unknown channel. Run `flutter channel` to switch to an official channel.
      If that doesn't fix the issue, reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
      Cannot resolve current version, possibly due to local changes.
      Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
    ! Unknown upstream repository.
      Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
    • Framework revision  (), 1970-01-01 11:00:00.000
    • Engine revision 2a3401c9bb
    • Dart version 3.0.3
    • DevTools version 2.23.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and upgrades.        

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.133
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 114.0.1823.43

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

How do I can fix it problems because I changed my laptop than I need to reset all environment

Comment: * flutter pub cache clean
* flutter clean
* flutter pub cache repair
* flutter pub get
Check your Flutter and Dart SDK versions: flutter doctor
Check for any specific error messages: flutter run -v

Comment: Run these commands to resolve the isseus

Answer (score 0):

it is because of your "places_service" package has not compatible with your current sdk. I can suggest you two ways for solving this issue.

1. remove the version of your package and set it to any like: places_servie: any
2. upgrade your current sdk to latest one it will solve

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command ***flutter doctor*** , you will get these type of result .

```
 Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.1, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

**But** , *I found there are some issues with your flutter installation process* .**Because you have " ! Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown on channel unknown at C:\flutter"** while running flutter doctor . Kindly reinstall you **flutter SDK** . Also ,upgrade you ***place_service*** to latest version .

Comment: I had do reinstall, but still error, and new path is C:\src\flutter

Comment: @Stanley Do you still get the Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown on channel unknown at C:\flutter ?

Comment: yes, how to upgrade the new path? I mean, upgrade place_service

Comment: @Stanley You can use https://pub.dev/packages/places_service and upgrade to latest version .

Comment: same, when i used `flutter pakeage get`, I got this error `depends on places_service >=0.1.0+1 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.17.0, version solving failed.`

Comment: @Stanley . Actually , there is not issues with place_service . Its the problem with Flutter SDK version compatability . Run the command Flutter --version . It will get the flutter version  . Download the new Flutter SDK from https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows and then Unzip in C/ flutter  .  Update your Flutter SDK path to the Environment variable  and System variable C/Flutter/bin. Then Restart the System

Comment: @Stanley Use places_service: ^0.1.3 in pubspec.yaml file .

Comment: In the `c:\src\flutter` I tried used `flutter doctor -v` it's working, but in my project, it's had errors